# AWS autoscaling: downscale too fast

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

The scaling configured according to cpu usage:
[image]

On the chart it's about 8 minutes between upscaling and 2 mins between downscalings. 
[image]

We cannot upscale faster because an instance requires ~5min to launch, however I'd like to have downscaling with similar delay too. Other variables:

Default Cooldown 600

Health Check Grace Period 400

What's configured wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In your decrease logic, increase the value for "consecutive periods...".

That should induce delay in your ASG shrink actions.

Comment: but '4 consecutive periods of 300 seconds' is 20 minutes, why we have only two?

Comment: @Putnik probably because the "remove 2" condition is being hit, so 2 are being removed at relatively the same time.